# datalist input autocpmlete lose focus after select a value

Tags: jquery

I have input with a datalist to perform auto completion. The datalist is dynamic. I do that as follows

I have a function as follows:

```
$(function () {
            $("#to").on("input", function (e) {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val === "")
                    return;
                if(val.length < 2) return;
                console.log(val);
                $.getJSON("/code", {term: val}, function (data) {
                    var dataList = $("#list");
                    dataList.empty();
                    //console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
                            //console.log(obj.value);
                            //console.log(obj.label);
                            var opt = $("<option></option>").attr("value",obj.value).text(obj.label);
                            dataList.append(opt);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

The problem with this function is that, when i select a value from data list, the input event is triggered again, so I need to click escape to exit form the selection. How can I lose focus when select a value form data list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did the trick as follows by checking the content of my datalist.

```
if ($('#list option').filter(function () {
                return this.value === val;
            }).length) {
                return;
            }
```